# Why do I get a RubyVersionMismatch when calling heroku toolbelt CLI with rake?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rvm, heroku-toolbelt

I'm trying to execute the `heroku` CLI from a rake task:

```
  1 task :call_heroku do     
  2   `heroku pgbackups:url --remote staging`
  3 end
```

`bundle exec rake call_heroku` returns the following output:

```
        /home/joe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/
definition.rb:390:in `validate_ruby!': Your Ruby version is 1.9.3,but your 
Gemfile specified 2.1.0 (Bundler::RubyVersionMismatch)
            from /home/joe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/
bundler.rb:116:in `setup'
            from /home/joe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/
bundler/setup.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
            from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
            from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        --remote staging
```

Executing `heroku pgbackups:url --remote staging` from the command line returns the expected URL. Do I have a problem with my rvm or heroku CLI configuration?

Environment details:

Rails 3.2.17

heroku:

```
joe@warpaint ~/dev/project (master) $ heroku version
heroku-toolbelt/2.39.0 (i686-linux) ruby/1.9.3
```

rvm:

```
joe@warpaint ~/dev/project (master) $ rvm version

rvm 1.25.22 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]


joe@warpaint ~/dev/project (master) $ rvm list

rvm rubies

   jruby-1.7.1 [ i386 ]
   ree-1.8.7-2012.02 [ i686 ]
   ruby-1.8.7-p374 [ i686 ]
   ruby-1.9.2-p320 [ i686 ]
   ruby-1.9.3-p0 [ i686 ]
   ruby-1.9.3-p362 [ i686 ]
   ruby-1.9.3-p392 [ i686 ]
   ruby-1.9.3-p448 [ i686 ]
   ruby-1.9.3-p484 [ i686 ]
   ruby-2.0.0-p0 [ i686 ]
 * ruby-2.0.0-p247 [ i686 ]
   ruby-2.0.0-p353 [ i686 ]
   ruby-2.0.0-p451 [ i686 ]
   ruby-2.0.0-preview2 [ i686 ]
=> ruby-2.1.0 [ i686 ]
   ruby-head [ i686 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

ruby:

```
joe@warpaint ~/dev/project (master) $ ruby -v
ruby 2.1.0p0 (2013-12-25 revision 44422) [i686-linux]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It turns out that this is a bundler issue. Some digging around led me to this issue:
https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/2355, which was resolved by @indirect and mentions using `Bundler.with_clean_env` ([more](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/2355) on this command).

Now my task above becomes:

```
  1 task :call_heroku do     
  2   Bundler.with_clean_env { p `heroku pgbackups:url --remote staging` }
  3 end
```

And all is well!

Answer (score 2):

it is just because you have install `heroku` in `1.9.3` ruby.

Install heroku in `2.1.0` ruby , it will good then.

Comment: How do I install heroku in 2.1.0 ruby, exactly? Should I uninstall my version and re-install using https://toolbelt.heroku.com/?

Comment: select ruby 2.1.0 and install heroku in normal way.

Comment: I ran `rvm use 2.1.0 && wget -qO- https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh`. Then I retried `bundle exec rake call_heroku` and experienced the same error as above.

Comment: what is the output of this command `heroku --version`, it should have 2.1.0 ruby in it.

Comment: I installed and reinstalled several times. The `heroku --version` always has 1.9.3 in it. Perhaps this is an RVM issue? (Also see answer below)